# how to return old syntax highlighting behavior in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, syntax, themes, textmate

Recent updates have killed javascript syntax and I want to return past behavior. Tell me how to do this?
Here the current behavior is shown: now functions such as "console", "JSON" are displayed in the color of ordinary variables, although they are built-in language functions. Recognizing them becomes much more complicated and unpleasant - everything merges into one mass

[new behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMMK.png)

[old behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIYVA.png)

Comment: To tune the editor's syntax highlighting colors, use `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` in your user settings `settings.json` file.. [Customizing a Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

Comment: The problem was solved like this:
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "semanticHighlighting": false
   }

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved like this:
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "semanticHighlighting": false
    }